# Existence of Limits of complex functions

Tags: complex-numbers

I just started to study complex variables and had a problem in trying to show that the limit does not exist.
$F(z) =\frac{(x +y) ^2}{x^2 + y^2}$ as $z$ approaches $0$.

I was getting $1$, which to me showed that the limit existed.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your equations.

Comment: How did you get 1?

Comment: I plugged in 0 for x and evaluated, then plugged in 0 for y and evaluated.

Comment: $z$ can approach zero in a multitude of ways. You have tried just one of them, however, there is an infinite number of paths from any point in the complex plane to $0$, and you should try a few of them and see what happens to the limit

Comment: @YuriyS I'm not quite sure I understand what you mean, do you mean plugging in different numbers or?

Comment: @user607715, you don't quite understand the concept of limits... What do you know about sequences and limits of sequences? Limits of functions are defined in a similar way. You have to consider a sequence of points approaching some final point and the sequence of function values along the way

Comment: @YuriyS thank you for your help and response.

Comment: Here's a very nice book for anyone who wants to understand complex analysis better http://pipad.org/tmp/Needham.visual-complex-analysis.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some visual aid, courtesy of Mathematica, to supplement Sobi's answer:

[image]

As we can see, the function looks terrible, and its value at $0$ is not defined.

Comment: I'm very grateful.

Comment: @user607715, you are welcome, but I think Sobi's answer deserves to be the accepted one (unless someone else provides a better answer). My post is just an illustration, since I can't put a picture in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that the limit should exist and be equal *along any curve that converges to the origin*. So for instance, if you take the curve $x=t, y=0$ (i.e. if you approach the origin along the real axis), you find that
$$\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{(x +y) ^2}{x^2 + y^2} = \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{(0+t)^2}{0^2+t^2} = \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{t^2}{t^2} = 1.$$
What happens if you instead take the curve $x=t, y=t$ (i.e. if you approach the origin at a 45 degree angle)?